# How do I get rid of smoke smell

Tags: smell, garage, smoking

I live in a town house and my garage connects to my neighbors and shares a wall.  My neighbors are always smoking in their garage all the time and now the smell is wafting into my garage.  It is starting to make my car smell of smoke. I am just looking for something to help eliminate the smell so my garage and car don't smell of smoke.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of wafting through a solid wall, the smoke is probably coming through some crack/seam/open area where the air can flow between two garages. Maybe locate and seal those with canned foam.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to make smoke smell disappear:

1. Take a wet towel, not too wet. Towel of this kind would be sufficient.

[image: Towel]

2. Wave it around the garage and car. It will absorb all the smoke smell.
3. After that you can use room freshener/perfume, which is optional though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Ron that you need to seal the wall to prevent further smoke infiltration.

But you already have a noticeable odor - in order to do something about that, you need to do 2 things:

1) Air out the space.  Leave the garage door open as much as possible.  If there's a way to run a fan so it pushes air through and out the garage, do so - open a window in the house, open the garage door, put a box fan in the door between the garage and the house.

2) Clean and deodorize what's in the garage.  The inside of your car, anything you store in the garage, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from airing and washing your garage and car out, you can use odor absorbers to soak the smoke smell up. Charcoal, Febreeze, lemon and water, just water, charcoal, and vinegar are capable of helping get rid of the odors in your car. Just having these materials in an area with a smoky smell is often enough to help dispell the odor.